# non-cartesian set product?

Tags: products

Foremost, this question is asked from a point of a computer scientist undergrad, so please don't nag me for inconsistent notation, or lack of proper vocabulary.

Is there a concept in mathematics for a non-cartesian product of sets, i.e. a one which maps to a set of products of all elements from two sets? Let me define more formally:

$$
for\quad { S }_{ 1 },{ S }_{ 2 },{ S }_{ 3 }\subseteq \mathbb{R},\quad let\quad { f }: ({ S }_{ 1 },{ S }_{ 2 })\mapsto { S }_{ 3 }\\ so\quad that\quad {f}({ S }_{ 1 },{ S }_{ 2 })=\{ x|\exists a\in { S }_{ 1 },\exists b\in { S }_{ 2 },(ab=x)\} 
$$
For example: let ${ S }_{ 1 }=\{ 1, 2, 3\}$ and ${ S }_{ 2 }=\{ 4, 5\}$.
Therefore ${ S }_{ 1 }.{ S }_{ 2 }=\{ 1*4,\quad 1*5,\quad 2*4,\quad 2*5,\quad 3*4,\quad 3*5\} =\{ 4,5,8,10,12,15\}$

It would seem to me that this concept would be useful and widely used in mathematics, yet I have never stumbled upon it. Does this concept exist? If yes, where and how is it used? Or is it something that I inherently misunderstood about sets that prevents such concept to be useful?

Comment: This is called binary operation in set theory.

Comment: is $R$ a function or a set?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, used R for a set of real but R with dot suffix as a binary relation.

Comment: @Raven; bad practice - you'll only confuse people. In LaTex use \mathbb{R} for $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The set of reals is denoted \mathbb{R} in tex

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It's called a **[binary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation)**. A common application is Graph Theory, esp. the [graph product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_product).

Its similar to a **[Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)**, but this returns an ordered pair $(a,b)$ without defining an operation on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: What exactly is called a binary operation? A binary operation requires a set to operate on. The operation OP is talking about is an operation on subsets of a set which is derived from a binary operation on a set. It is a very special form of a binary operation on the set of subsets of a given set with a binary operation on it. It is incorrect to say that it is the same as "binary operation".

Comment: f is a binary operation, equally defined on $S_k$ as on  $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 5):

The common notation for the element-wise product of two sets (which must both be subsets of some given magma, i.e., a set with an operation) is $AB$ or $A\cdot B$ or, if the operation is addition, $A+B$ (or any other symbol for the operation) and is defined as the set $\{a+b\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$ (suitably adapted to use the relevant operation symbol). It is commonly used throughout mathematics whenever convenient.

Comment: The addition is called "Minkowski sum", but I don't know about the product.

Answer (score 0):

What you are computing is the set of inner products of two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. The inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ takes two $n$-dimensional vectors and maps it to a real number. It satisfies the following properties: $x,y,x_1,y_1\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in \mathbb{R}$.

1. $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle y,x\rangle$
2. $\langle \alpha_1 x_1+\alpha_2 x_2,y\rangle =\alpha_1\langle x_1,y\rangle+ \alpha_2\langle x_2,y\rangle$
3. $\langle x,x\rangle =0$, if $x=\overline{0}$ (zero vector),
   $\langle x,x\rangle >0$, if $x\neq \overline{0}$.

You can see multiplication of two real numbers satisfy all these properties.

So now compute $S_3$, the set of all inner products of $S_1,S_2\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.
$S_3=\{x\in \mathbb{R} \mid \exists s_1\in S_1, \exists s_2\in S_2, \langle s_1,s_2\rangle=x\}$.

If you repalce $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}$ then you get your product. So, yes, that product is a well-known concept in mathematics.